# JSON with line breaks can not be parsed via JSON.parse()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this string

```
{"cb":15,"cl":12,"cr":18,"ct":3,"id":"6yIGexevqu9RGM:","ml":{"366":{"bh":96,"bw":112,"o":0},"454":{"bh":93,"bw":88,"o":0}},"oh":500,"os":"42KB","ou":"http://albums.songspk.link/images/cover/55553137088b0humnava.jpg","ow":500,"pt":"Humnava
                                                            - Hamari Ahduri Kahani (2015) Download Mp3 Songs
                                                            ...","rh":"albums.songspk.link","ru":"http://albums.songspk.link/audio-mp3-single-track/humnava_hamar_adhuri_kahani_mp3_song","s":"","th":112,"tu":"https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q\u003dtbn:ANd9GcTlkE4gq7VQB5vB8-35jIF8YBh5KP14GsquWY1allab1-KnL07cREXXajV0_w","tw":112}
```

If you copy and paste it to [JSONLINT](http://jsonlint.com/), you will see it shows an error because of the line break. If I remove the line breaks the error gets resolved. Is there any way I can parse the string to JSON in JavaScript?

Comment: replace real line break with `\n` (line break equivalent)

Comment: Where does the JSON come from? You should reach out to them and tell them that they produce invalid JSON. The solution is to fix the JSON, not to find ways to parse broken JSON.

Comment: You've got two answers telling you to work around it. Don't. Get the owner(s) of the server to fix the JSON.

Comment: If you copied it from somewhere, you need to replace real line breaks. Do it in notepad++(with regexp mode enabled, replace `\n` with `\\n`) or remove it at all in online services like this http://www.textfixer.com/tools/remove-line-breaks.php

Comment: @FelixKling It's from google ... i am crawling google for images in there right box when you search any movie name..!!!! ;)

Comment: I doubt Google would produce invalid JSON, so I'm not sure what you mean by "it's form Google". *"i am crawling google for images"* sounds like you may be creating the JSON yourself one way or the other.

Comment: @FelixKling   document.querySelectorAll("[class='rg_meta']");   try this in console... there will be json in text inside div... i was extracting and using that...!!! Yes but search for any movie name like "avengers age of ultron" or any thing else... it gives the images json.

Comment: I see. I'm pretty sure what you are doing violates Google's Terms of Service. However, I can parse the data of all 121 of these nodes on the current site without any problems. Coincidence?

Comment: yes.. but google actually itself retrives this data from other websites... i know scrapping google is forbiden (what an irony for the biggest scrapper ever written)... @FelixKling

Comment: @FelixKling may be yes.... there are some movies for which data come with line breaks ... in that situation i needed this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution to my problem....

http://juristr.com/blog/2010/05/n-will-break-your-json-jquery-wcf/

In this article... there is this function... for my thing i changed "\n" with "" [blank space] as i only want JSON to be parsed.

**FUNCTION IN WEBSITE**

```
function escapeNewLineChars(valueToEscape) {
   if (valueToEscape != null && valueToEscape != "") {
      return valueToEscape.replace(/\n/g, "\\n");
   } else {
      return valueToEscape;
   } 
}
```

**WHAT I AM USING NOW**

```
function escapeNewLineChars(valueToEscape) {
   if (valueToEscape != null && valueToEscape != "") {
      return valueToEscape.replace(/\n/g, " ");
   } else {
      return valueToEscape;
   } 
}
```

and my problem got solved.... i replace "\n" with " " ...

Answer (score 0):

The [JSON specification](http://json.org/) does not mention literal newline as a "char" as part of string values, so you can't just insert in to strings. You can use the escape sequence `\n` instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Bare linebreaks can't occur in JSON strings; you have to escape them**. Depending on the way the string is encoded, the proper escape sequence could be `\n`, `\r\n`, or `\r`. That last one is very unlikely these days, but it can happen if you might be dealing with files that were created on pre-OSX Macs.

However it happens, you need to go through the string and make sure you've escaped any linebreaks within it, and then put *that* into the JSON file. Alternatively, you could remove all linebreaks from the string, but this might not be feasible for your application.